# Typescript with Jest and Jasmine (tests pass, tslint fails)

Tags: typescript, jestjs

I have tests passing with jasmine (library tests) and jest (snapshot tests) by including this line at the top of my test files:

```
/// <reference path="../../node_modules/@types/jasmine/index.d.ts" />

// -> in my jest test files
/// <reference path="../../node_modules/@types/jest/index.d.ts" />
```

However when I run `tslint` I get Duplicate errors such as

```
ERROR in [at-loader] ./node_modules/@types/jest/index.d.ts:12:13
    TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'fdescribe'.
```

The problem is I cannot actually exclude the `d.ts` files for jasmine and jest as I need them for my tests, but I want to exclude them from my `tslint`...is there a way to configure this? I saw some issues but no real solution was posted.

Answer (score 1):

Managed to get it working by telling my tsconfig to exclude my test files (which end in spec.tsx)

```
"exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "**/*.spec.tsx",
    // ... etc
```